# Auto executable permission to certain type of files

Tags: linux, vim, emacs

Is there a way I can configure my linux box or editor like vim/emacs to automatically give executable file permission to certain file types ?

Currently if I want to write a bash script I need to manually give executable permission. 
I am looking for a way that whenever I create file having 
.bash or .sh extension 
It should give executable permission to that file.

Comment: @JohnWatts sorry I realized after posting question that is should belong to super user. How can I move question to super user.

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I think it will get moved by the close operation automatically. It gets closed here and opened there, once it gets enough votes.

Comment: @VivekGoel you should also be looking at the presence of the magic cookie "hash-bang", not file extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the Emacs aspect of it definitely does fit on StackOverflow.  Here is a bit of code to add to your init file to mark magic number "hash-bang" files executable:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)
```

Comment: Agreed. Almost every Emacs question involves a programmatic elisp solution, so such questions belong here IMO.

Answer (score 4):

One vim equivalent:

```
au BufWritePost,BufFilePost *.sh call system("chmod +x ".expand("%"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) makes files with shebang lines executable, among other things.